# Alphabet sorting does not work properly with unique characters

Tags: views

I've a view with sorting by first character and it does not work properly for unique characters (f.x. danish characters: ø å æ).

What should I do in order to sort they properly?

Thanks.

Comment: How do you sort (e.g. delegating it to **Views**, with a custom PHP function, or by SQL `ORDER BY`)?  What locale and collating sequence is set for your sorting method?

Comment: It's just a view that sort my value by alphabet (the sort column is just a text field, i.e. 'Company Name').

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up with writing my own module. It uses hook [views_query_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_query_alter/7) and change SQL query little bit. Module does not have any settings in UI but hardcoded variables so you need to adjust it in order to solve issue with sorting.

```
<?php

/**
 * @file
 * Implements hook_views_query_alter().
 *
 * it adds 'COLLATE utf8_language_ci' to languages that are not supported by default
 * so far there are only few languages we have issues with.
 */
function views_collate_sorting_views_query_alter(&$view, &$query) {
  // views where we want to enable collation
  $views = array(
    'dictionary_overview'
  );

  // exit if the current view is not specified
  if (!in_array ($view->name, $views)) {
    return FALSE;
  }

  // define list of languages we support
  $map = array(
    'da' => 'utf8_danish_ci',
    'sv' => 'utf8_swedish_ci',
    'nb' => 'utf8_danish_ci',
    'es' => 'utf8_spanish_ci',
    'pl' => 'utf8_polish_ci',
  );

  // get current utf8
  $l = $GLOBALS['language']->language;

  if (!array_key_exists ($l, $map)) {
    return FALSE;
  }

  // get current utf8 language which we are going to add to all sort fields
  $utf8 = $map[$l];

  // add COLLATE utf8_xx_ci to all sort criteria
  $orderby = &$query->orderby;
  foreach ($orderby as &$order) {
    $order['field'] .= ' COLLATE ' . $utf8;
  }
}
```